# higher precision in python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy, precision, scientific-computing

I am running some `python` v3.3.2 scripts that use `numpy` and `scipy` and `math`. I am suspecting that there is an issue of numerical precision in my computation, and I would like to increase the precision in some particular modules that I have written and see if it makes a difference in the final result. In my module I am using some algebraic manipulations and `numpy.sqrt`.

How do I manipulate the precision of the computations in a module that is already written by me?(I can modify it). I have seen that there are several modules available like `decimal` and `mpmath` and `bigfloat`, and I was trying to figure out from the documentation which one would be more suitable for my task. The first one is already installed and I should install the other two. Ideally I would like to write a command on the top of the module and specifying the precision that I need in that module, does something like that exist?

EDIT ---------

I think the problem may come from computation of second derivative:

```
def secondderivative(x,y):
  xl     = np.roll(x,1) # x1
  xr     = np.roll(x,-1)# x3
  yl     = np.roll(y,1)
  yr     = np.roll(y,-1)

  ind    = np.where(np.isnan(y) | np.isnan(yl) | np.isnan(yr) )[0]

  deriv2 = (2 * yl / ((x - xl)  * (xr - xl))
        - 2 * y  / ((xr - x)  * (x - xl))
        + 2 * yr / ((xr - xl) * (xr - x)))

  for i in ind:
    deriv2[i] = np.nan

  deriv2[0]             = np.nan
  deriv2[len(deriv2)-1] = np.nan
  return deriv2
```

I have seen the result from gradient is completely different:

```
np.gradient(np.gradient(y,x),x)
```

Comment: As you mention Numerical Recipes in your comments below, you must be aware that computing second derivatives via direct finite differences can lead to precision issues (see Section 5.7 of [NR](http://apps.nrbook.com/empanel/index.html#). They also mention solutions to that problem such as Richardson interpolation (probably not applicable in your case though), Chebyshev approximations, Padé approximants and others. Try those.

Comment: @JoeyDumont actually I have verified that, on a typical example function for my application, my computation of the second derivative is accurate more than 1e-3 in terms of relative error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your code is based on numpy/scipy and co., you can only use the types supported by these libs. Here is the [overview](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html).

The paragraph [Extended precision](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html#extended-precision) will be relevant for you.

Combining numpy/scipy with decimal, mpmath and co. would need a lot of work (in the general case)!

It would have been much more wise to show some code so that one could guess what's going on. Even with limited precision, there are techniques which makes a difference: e.g. [iterative-refinement in solving linear systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_refinement).

Comment: I assume the standard computation in `numpy` uses double precision. Maybe I can decrease the precision and see if it makes a difference. how do I decrease the precision globally in all the module?

Comment: You can't globally set the precision of your operations. You just decide on the precision within your array and the algorithmics will reflect somehow. So start with either ```np.float32``` or ```np.float64``` in your array and keep this type during your computations.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a part of the code that may cause the issue

Comment: That's not my area of expertise, but: it looks you are calculating a symbolic / closed-form gradient while numpy's ```np.gradient()``` should calculate a numerica approximation. Yeah, they should be similar, but not necessarily equal imho. If you want to experiment more: autograd can calculate gradients by symbolic/automatic differentiation for *some numpy code*.

Comment: this is not symbolic derivative. It is second order numerical derivative computed with the formula provided by numerical receipts, because this is not implemented in numpy/scipy with inhomogeneous x-axis

Comment: Have you considered using `sympy` (http://www.sympy.org)? It could most likely do a symbolic derivation of your function and then feed this back to `numpy`. Of course you would have to rewrite some of your code, but likely only the function and it's derivatives.

Comment: @Hannebambel I don't need symbolic derivative. I am just trying to compute the second derivative of a function already sampled into an array

Comment: @simona: I know you try to work numerically and run into precision issues. That's why I suggested to try to circumvent the numerical issues by using symbolic calculations. This is of course only easy if your original function can be expressed explicitly. If you would say something about your original function then maybe someone can give you some help by using a different numerical differentiation method better adapted to your problem.

Comment: there is no original function. it is an output obtained numerically from another simulation. it is intrinsically sampled on some array

Comment: Ah, in that case you know pretty much nothing about your function. Well, that means you need the most generic method and try brute-force higher precision as you intend to. Or try to get your simulation to output more intermediate values, if feasible. Good luck!